# Save colorbar for scatter plot separately

Tags: python, matplotlib, colorbar

I've got scatter plot with colorbar which I save as PNG image. I need the plot to be of a certain figsize but adding colorbar scales original plot.

```
import pylab as plt

plt.figure(figsize=FIGSIZE)
plt.scatter(X, Y, c=Z, s=marker_size, norm=LogNorm(), vmin=VMIN, vmax=VMAX, cmap=CMAP,rasterized=True,lw=0,)
CB = plt.colorbar(ticks=TICKS, format=FORMAT)
```

How could I save original plot (with figsize set as above) and colorbar as two separate images?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The obvious answer is "plot your colorbar separately". You need to create a new figure window and plot your colorbar there, in order to prevent your first figure from being distorted. Small example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np    # only for dummy data

X,Y = np.mgrid[-2:3,-2:3]
Z = np.random.rand(*X.shape)
FIGSIZE = (2,3)

plt.figure(figsize=FIGSIZE)
mpb = plt.pcolormesh(X,Y,Z,cmap='viridis')
# plot the original without a colorbar
plt.savefig('plot_nocbar.png')

# plot a colorbar into the original to see distortion
plt.colorbar()
plt.savefig('plot_withcbar.png')

# draw a new figure and replot the colorbar there
fig,ax = plt.subplots(figsize=FIGSIZE)
plt.colorbar(mpb,ax=ax)
ax.remove()
plt.savefig('plot_onlycbar.png')

# save the same figure with some approximate autocropping
plt.savefig('plot_onlycbar_tight.png',bbox_inches='tight')
```

Consider the following four figures that were produced (click to view properly):

[image: no colorbar] [image: distorted with colorbar] [image: separate colorbar with much white] [image: cropped colorbar]

The first is a saved version of the figure without a call to `colormap`. This is fine, this is what you want to preserve. The second figure shows what happens if we call `colorbar` without any extra fuss: it takes some space from the original figure, and this is what you want to prevent.

You have to open a new figure (and axes) using `plt.subplots`, with the size of your original figure. This way you can be sure that the produced colorbar will be the same size as if it was drawn in your original figure. In the above setup I let `matplotlib` determine the size of the colorbar itself; but then afterward we need to delete the auxiliary axes that would pollute the resulting plot. (The other option would be to create a single axes in the new figure manually, with the expected size of the colorbar. I suspect this is not a feasible course of action.)

Now, as you can see in the third plot, the empty space left after the deleted axes is clearly visible in the resulting plot (but the size of the colorbar is perfect, correspondingly). You can either cut this white space off manually in post-production, or use something that autocrops your colorbar image.

I also included a version of the plot wherein matplotlib itself crops most of the figure: the `bbox_inches='tight'` keyword argument to `savefig` does exactly this. The upside is that the resulting image file only contains the colorbar (as seen above in the fourth image), but the size of the resulting colorbar will be slightly different from your original. Depending on your specific needs, you'll need to experiment with the available methods to come up with a solution that's most convenient for you.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you! I used your last example.
The only thing I cannot understand is why setting dpi and figsize gives the resulting image of some unexpected size (I set figsize=(3,8) and dpi=80 but the resulting plot is 144x660 pixels instead of 240x640 pixels)

Comment: @AntonK If you set `dpi=80` in the call to `figure()` it will only affect the output on the screen. In order to get the expected dpi in the output file, you need to set `dpi=80` in the call to `plt.savefig("filename.png", dpi=80)`.  (default is 100 I think) Furthermore using `bbox_inches='tight'` will change the figsize (that's why you use it, right?) so your output image size is unpredictable. If you need a specific output size, you should not call `bbox_inches='tight'`.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest thanks for the input, I'm entirely unfamiliar with the `dpi` setting. As for the colorbar, I believe this resizing would be OK for OP: what matters is that the plot itself is of a given size, and then a separate colorbar can be put next to it (otherwise the question doesn't seem to make sense, at least to me). In this case, what matters is that the generated colorbar corresponds to what would be plotted for the figure, which is why I suggested starting from a figure of the same size (but then it does indeed get cropped to the auto-set size of the colorbar).

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest sorry, it took me a while to understand your point about figure size:) Yes, you're also right about that, due to cropping the resulting aspect ratio will not be the input figure aspect ratio. But that should be fine, since otherwise OP will end up with either extra leg room in the figure, or a horribly ugly colorbar.